# Variable percentage displaying zero value

Tags: c++

Hey guys i have a bug that i am unable to detect. Kindly help me out. In this code i want to calculate a percentage but after the calculation there is a zero value store in the variable "percentage"

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int total_marks, obtained_marks, percentage;
    total_marks = 1100;
    cout << "enters yours obtained marks"<<endl;
    cin >> obtained_marks;
    percentage = (obtained_marks / total_marks) * 100;
    cout << "yours percentage =" << percentage;
    if (percentage >= 60)
    {
        cout << "you have passed with first division";
    }
    cout << "yours pecentage is=" << percentage;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you using `int` ?

Comment: Because all the variables contain number without decimal , i also use float with percentage variable but still give zero value.

Comment: if the user enters eg 100, then 100/1100 has decimal places

Comment: ok i change the data type but still got the same bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer division truncates towards zero.

Given

```
int total_marks, obtained_marks, percentage;
```

and

```
percentage = (obtained_marks / total_marks) * 100;
```

if `obtained_marks` is less than `total_marks`, the value of `(obtained_marks / total_marks)` will be zero.  In that case,

```
percentage = (obtained_marks / total_marks) * 100;
```

will also be zero.

Even

```
percentage = (obtained_marks / total_marks) * 100.0;
```

will be zero, because the value in the parenthesis is still zero.

One better way would be:

```
percentage = ( 100 * obtained_marks ) / total_marks;
```

Answer (score 0):

obtained marks and total marks are integers so you are getting zero when you divide. Change your data types to float or double.

Comment: could you please explain this, I got my answer but briefly explain your line.

Comment: @OsamaJutt You are using integer math to compute a number less that zero, which will be truncated to zero.  For example: 25/100 in integer math is .25 but the decimal places are deleted and you are left with zero. If you change all your data types to float or double then you will not lose those decimal places and you will get the answer you expect.